# Pagination for category in php

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a code pagination for category in php, this should display all items from database by selecting id and category id
It's displaying only first page, but when I click second page it's not displaying other list. 
Where can I fix to display all items of list?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    include("conn.php");
    $cid=intval($_GET['cid']);

        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select count(id) from adverts where category='$cid'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

    $rows = $row[0];

    $page_rows = 3;

    $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);

    if($last < 1){
        $last = 1;
    }

    $pagenum = 1;

    if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
        $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
    }

    if ($pagenum < 1) { 
        $pagenum = 1; 
    } 
    else if ($pagenum > $last) { 
        $pagenum = $last; 
    }

    $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE category='$cid'  $limit");

    $paginationCtrls = '';

    if($last != 1){

    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'" class="btn btn-default">Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';

        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'" class="btn btn-default">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
            }
        }
    }

    $paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';

    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'" class="btn btn-default">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'" class="btn btn-default">Next</a> ';
    }
    }


?>
```

Comment: Use `TOP` and `LIMIT` in mysql query

Comment: @sanychhoilo TOP isn't a thing.

Comment: Add OFFSET to you database query. The length of the offset should be equal to the LIMIT * page_number.

Comment: Where should I put OFFSET? I need display all items from database by using pagination? Could you explain with code if it's possible.